# Please I wish to use the reduce method on my javascript array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a total array that has other arrays of values inside.
  I wish to add the nested values with the help of forEach and reduce()

```
// My main array
Total = [
  [ 1, 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, 1 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]

// The code I have

  Total.forEach(function(element) {
    element.reduce(function(a,b) {
        console.log(a+b)
    }, 0)
})

// Output not as expected!
    1
NaNNaNNaN0 NaNNaNNaN1 NaNNaNNaN0 NaNNaNNaN0 NaNNaNNaN1 []
```

What I want is for example, The first forEach should give the sum of `1+0+1+0 = 2...`  And so on

Comment: What I want is for example, The first forEach should give the sum of 1+0+1+0 = 2... And so on

Comment: please add the whole result as well

Comment: Your `reduce` function needs to **`return`** something…!

Comment: @NinaScholz Not clear..
   If I can get something like

**[ 1, 0, 1, 0 ], = 2
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], = 1
  [ 1, 0, 0, 1 ], = 2
  [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], = 1
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], = 1
  [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ], = 1
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], = 0
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]  = 0**
        Then good

Comment: @deceze which in my case, It'll be what i logged (a+b)

Comment: No, that’s not returning anything, so on the next iteration `a` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Is that the case??

Answer (score 1):

Try this aproach, using a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) nested with a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const Total = [
    [1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
];

let res = Total.map(x => x.reduce((res, curr) => res += curr, 0));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thats it. Perfect!! Thanks ,:)

Comment: Your welcome, take into consideration choice one of the answers as correct if you can

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code

```js
var Total = [
  [ 1, 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, 1 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ];

  function myFunction(){
    for(let i=0 ;i<Total.length;i++){

    console.log(Total[i].reduce(getSum));

    }
  }

  function getSum(total, num) {
  return total + num;
}
myFunction();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You are welcome...If the answer is helpful you can vote it... Thanks :)